# OBIEE Column selector with no results

Tags: obiee

I'm trying to create an analysis based on errors, so I hope I have little to no value in this analysis but I need a column selector to switch between different measures which can have an error. 
When I switch to a measure which doesn't contain any errors, I get a nice 'no results' message but also my column selector disappears. How do you keep this even when the analysis results in 'no results' or maybe another way to work around this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) "Back" in the browser :-)
b) "Clear My Customization" in a dashboard context
c) Instead of a column selector, you can move that logic to a dashboard prompt which switches out the measure in the analysis itself. Since the prompt isn't in-line with the analysis code but a stand-alone object it will stay unaffected by "No results".

You'd say '"Measure"."@{vMeasureSelection}{Count}" in the analysis column formula and then have the presentation variable value from a prompt passed in there.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for the update, these are actually nice solutions, especially 'c'!